# Mysql Group By Date

Tags: mysql, date, group-by

I have Table with 3 Columns, Column1 with Date and Column2 stores Points which is nothing but Some random Number between 1 to 9  and column 3 which have some unique email address in every cell.

Now I want to add the points grouped by date for last 5 days.
That is if I have 3 rows for day one, 1 rows for day two, 3 rows for day 3  and 2 rows for day 4 & 5  I should get the sum of points of these 11 rows grouped by date as 5 rows for five days.

**Input**

**Date**              **Points**
           **Email**

2012-07-01                                                                         5                                                      a@sample.com
2012-07-01                                                                         6                                                  b@sample.com
2012-07-01                                                                         2                                                   c@sample.com

2012-07-02                                                                         5                                                  d@sample.com

2012-07-03                                                                         8                                                  e@sample.com
2012-07-03                                                                         7
                                                  f@sample.com
2012-07-03                                                                         1
                                                  y@sample.com

2012-07-04                                                                         3                                                  x@sample.com

2012-07-04                                                                         2                                                  f@sample.com

2012-07-05                                                                         3                                                  g@sample.com
2012-07-05                                                                         9                                                  b@sample.com

**Output**

**Date**              **Points**

2012-07-01                                      13 
2012-07-02                                        5 
2012-07-03                                      16 
2012-07-04                                         5 
2012-07-05                                      12

Please suggest me a MySQL query for the above.

Comment: Do it yourself and learn some simple mysql queries

Comment: Agree with QuickSilver !! you need it. Also don't take reserved sql keywords like you took `Date` as column name.

Comment: +1, just to not kill your experience on StackOverFlow.  I don't agree with hammering someone over a (albeit) simple sql question.  So you down vote them and don't provide any hits or suggestions on where to start?

Answer (score 2):

```
select `Date`,sum(`Points`) from my_table group by `Date`;
```

Comment: Let me know whether i can do that if i have 3rd column which have different values in that

Comment: so what do you want in that case? then the query will return multiple rows.

Comment: @aprilleocean You have to explicitly mention how to group (or not group) additional columns with different data. It is not obvious how the machine should handle a situation like that

Answer (score 1):

```
select `Date`,sum(`Points`) from my_table group by `Date` Limit 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select Date,sum(Points) from my_table group by Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select [Date],SUM(Points)
from myTable1
group by [Date]
```

Comment: Let me know whether i can do that if i have 3rd column which have different values in every cell

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
SELECT date, SUM(points) AS points
FROM tbl
WHERE date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY
GROUP BY date
```