# Mysql Sum and Group By Method

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

**Input**

**Date**              **Points**
           **Email**

2012-07-01                                                                         5                                                      a@sample.com
2012-07-01                                                                         6                                                  b@sample.com
2012-07-01                                                                         2                                                   c@sample.com

2012-07-02                                                                         5                                                  d@sample.com

2012-07-03                                                                         8                                                  e@sample.com
2012-07-03                                                                         7
                                                  f@sample.com
2012-07-03                                                                         1
                                                  y@sample.com

2012-07-04                                                                         3                                                  x@sample.com

2012-07-04                                                                         2                                                  f@sample.com

2012-07-05                                                                         3                                                  g@sample.com
2012-07-05                                                                         9                                                  b@sample.com

**Output**

**Date**              **Points**

2012-07-01                                      13 
2012-07-02                                        5 
2012-07-03                                      16 
2012-07-04                                         5 
2012-07-05                                      12

Suggest me an MySQL Query for output like the above

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql Group By Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413162/mysql-group-by-date)

Answer (score 3):

try

```
 SELECT `date`, SUM(`Points`) AS sumPoint FROM table GROUP BY `date`
```

**Note :** dont forget to wrap `date` column with `` ` `` as **DATE** is reserve keyword of mySQL

Answer (score 0):

SELECT date, SUM(Points) AS sumPoint 
  FROM table 
 GROUP BY DATE(date)

Since date column might be datetime or date type in table