# Group by month/year and sum all data

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I'm trying to group some registers by months, having their values added, but no success up to now. I've been looking through the questions but haven't found this one.

My table is something like:

```
+----+------------+--------+--------+
| Id |    Date    | Field1 | Field2 |
+----+------------+--------+--------+
|  1 | 2014-02-01 |      4 |      5 |
|  2 | 2014-02-01 |      2 |      9 |
|  3 | 2014-02-20 |      2 |      6 |
|  4 | 2014-03-01 |      1 |      4 |
|  5 | 2014-04-03 |      1 |      5 |
+----+------------+--------+--------+
```

And I would like to finish with this:

```
+---------+--------+--------+
|  Date   | Field1 | Field2 |
+---------+--------+--------+
| 2014-02 |      8 |     20 |
| 2014-03 |      1 |      4 |
| 2014-04 |      1 |      5 |
+---------+--------+--------+
```

Any advice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql Sum and Group By Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425458/mysql-sum-and-group-by-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to group on the result of MySQL's [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function:

```
SELECT   DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m') Date, SUM(Field1) Field1, SUM(Field2) Field2
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m')
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4788e/1/0).